# how to print image in output of pycharm

Tags: python, image, pycharm, photo

I want to print an image in the pycharm output section.

```
from PIL import Image
i = Image.open("image.png")
i.show()
```

I enter this code but it does not show the image in pycharm.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Cannot repro in Pycharm. This opens an image fine. Make sure the current directory is correct and that you aren't getting any errors.

Comment: Also tried it here, no issues as stated by @Carcigenicate, the image opened in a separate window